# Values over a time period

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services, parameters

I would like to calculate a value in SQL that does the following:

if the user's inputted month parameter (I'm writing the SQL to aggregate information first then using SSRS) is 90 days or more past today (or the most recent data entry), then use the value for that month. Otherwise, if the month parameter is within 90 days of the report run date (or most recent data entry), use the most recent value that IS in fact 90 days past. For example, if I run the report in August and specify the month parameter as August, I will want the value from May. If I specify the month parameter as April, I want April's value since 90 days has gone by since then. Apologies if this isn't concise. I just would like some direction.

Cheers.

Comment: Is the month parameter an integer, a date/time or something else?

Comment: I think you should create a date variable called @StartDate.  Then assign it a value based on the inputted month parameter and use it in your select query.

Comment: Ian, the month parameter is a date/time currently. Dan, do you mean that as in make @startDate represent the time starting 90 days from the inputted parameter?

Comment: I mean that @StartDate should be set to the appropriate value based on the business rules you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @DanBracuk in the comments, you should probably take the parameter from SSRS and just update it based on the current date in your T-SQL code.

Say you have an SSRS parameter `Parameters!Month.Value` which gets passed to your stored procedure as `@Month`.

You can use `GETDATE()` and date functions like `DATEDIFF()` and `DATEADD()` to adjust `@Month` as required, e.g. in the stored procedure code something like:

```
select @Month = case when datediff(dd, @Month, getdate()) > 90
  then @Month
  else dateadd(dd, -90, @Month)
  end

select *
from MyTable
where MyDate < @Month
```

Update the first statement to meet your requirements; they seem a bit ambiguous at this point - apologies if I haven't understood the issue completely.

Comment: No worries, I am aware that I was a bit vague-I am actually doing something similar to that using dateadd(). Thanks for your help again.